# How to add text to router-link in vueJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to add some text to my "to" attribute using router-link. The code that I've written is

```
<router-link :to="camp._id" class="btn btn-primary">Know more</router-link> // it redirects to the route localhost/23bjsaki24r...
```

My requirement is to redirect the user to route - localhost/campgrounds/23bjsaki24r... instead of localhost/23bjsaki24r...
How can I add the string "campgrounds" before camp._id? Thanks

P.S: I'm using Vuejs

Comment: create a getter, look at [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html), or something like `:to="\`campgrounds\${camp._id}\`"`

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha, nvm, I dug through the vue-router docs and found the solution to it.

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```

This code snippet gave me a clearer understanding as to how to add additional parameters to my ":to" attribute.

The solution to my problem is

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Campground', params:{id:camp._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Know more</router-link>
```

Where the name: -takes in the component name and the params: -takes in the additional params that I've defined in my vue-router file.